# bokeh responsive row with items of unequal width

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to create a responsive row in bokeh 0.12.3 that contains a figure and a widgetbox, where the widgetbox has a much smaller width than the figure.

I'm able to achieve only the former with the following:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import RadioButtonGroup, TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("layout.html")

x = list(range(11))
y0 = x
y1 = [10 - i for i in x]
y2 = [abs(i - 5) for i in x]

# create a new plot
s1 = figure(width=600, plot_height=600, title=None)
s1.circle(x, y0, size=10, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

widgets = widgetbox([RadioButtonGroup(labels=["a", "b"]), TextInput(title="Input:", width=150)], width=150)

# put the results in a row
show(row([s1, widgets], responsive=True))
```

But this produces a responsive row where the width of the figure and widgetbox are equal. On tablets and mobile devices this can use up a lot of precious screen real-estate.

[The docs on layouts](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html)
specify that every item must have the same sizing mode, but not that every item must have the same size. I can't find any reference on setting relative sizes of each item.

I've played around with various options like `sizing_mode`, and setting widths at various levels, but I can't produce the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.12.3` equal-sizes for children is the only available option for the built-in Bokeh layouts such as `row`, etc. However, you could possibly embed the different children into your own HTML template, using the [`bokeh.embed`](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html) functions, which would give you finer control over things.

For instance, if you call:

```
components((s1, widgetbox))
```

Then you will get back a tuple:

```
(script, (s1_div, widgetbox_div))
```

You can template the `<script>` and the two `<div>`s into an HTML template. The components will show up wherever you insert the `<div>`s.

Comment: How can I use this method with a bokeh server to have dynamic dataset ? (to downsample for example). I can't find a way to have several components with a bokeh server solution...

Comment: That is still an open issue, but it is currently being worked on: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4986