# Bokeh layouts, rows with different heights

Tags: python, layout, bokeh

I am trying to have a bokeh layout which has 2 'sections'. The top section is one row filled with toggle buttons arranged horizontally (ie a very 'short' row taken up little vertical space).

I have functionality that shows these 2 sections (top one has toggle buttons, bottom section contains plots to be shown depending on toggle button `active` attribute values) except I can't seem to get the 'top' section to be only 10% of the vertical space and the 'bottom' section to always be 90% of the window (want it to dynamically size with window which I do with `stretch_both`). Also, doing `scale_width` works in filling up the vertical white space but then the xaxis is annoyingly out of the window and 1 plot cannot be contained in the window.

However, when I do that the top section always ends up occupying 50% of the window leaving a bunch of white space between the buttons and plots if there are only 1 or 2 plots being shown. Any tips on how to fill the white space with the plots (do not care about aspect ratio being changed in the process)?

Example code: (that yields the 50/50 vertical space split in window - lots of white space when only a few plots shown)

`from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.plotting import figure
layout = layout(children=[list of toggle buttons], sizing_mode='stretch_both')
...
...
figure = figure(x='x',y='y', source=some_source, sizing_mode='stretch_both')
...
layout.children.append(figure)`

This is what I'm getting (How do i fill the space between the buttons and the plots by having both plots expand their vertical size?)
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bokeh responsive row with items of unequal width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413198/bokeh-responsive-row-with-items-of-unequal-width)

Comment: Thanks @IanGoldby! That looks like a good solution. Haven't gotten it to work for my scenario but am definitely trying it out.