# Bokeh server : Customize row ratio

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using Bokeh to vizualize scientific data for a while and I fail to customize my layout as I wish.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button

tools_to_show = 'hover, box_zoom, save, reset, pan'
p = figure(tools=tools_to_show, output_backend = "webgl")
p.line([1, 2, 3, 4], [9, 5, 7, 6])

b_valid = Button(label="valid")

my_plot = row(p, b_valid, sizing_mode="stretch_both")

show(my_plot)
```

I have a plot area and a controls area. The controls area should be smaller, maybe 1/3 of available width to let the plot with a bigger area (2/3 of available width).

I'm using sizing_mode = "stretch_both" to be sure to use all available space in screen.

I need to keep using the bokeh server (bokeh serve myapp.py) to get python callback working, so the embbeded solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413198/bokeh-responsive-row-with-items-of-unequal-width) is not working for me.

Maybe there is a way with [serving directory](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#directory-format) with bokeh command because there is a template mechanism, but I can't figure how to get seperate div for plot and controls.

Have you any (simple) idea ?

**Edit :** it seems that it's not a feature currently available on bokeh. A promising solution is to be able to place components embedded in template using bokeh server : a[milestone](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4986) is scheduled

Comment: One idea could be adding a customJs callback to adjust width of the differents components directly in browser where it is possible to get real width of screen. I'm currently getting some difficulties because the layout is changing from Row to Column, for unknown reason. I'm still digging...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bokeh responsive row with items of unequal width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413198/bokeh-responsive-row-with-items-of-unequal-width)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I try to use bokeh server to have dynamic application (for example downsampling according to zoom), and I can't do it wit the solution suggested based on embbeded components. But thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that we are backing away from the built-in layout system for more than very simple things. PR [**`#7708`**](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7708) was just merged an will be in the upcoming `0.13.0` release. When `0.13.0` is available, you can embed individual document roots separately in temlates, e.g. if you define five plots in a Bokeh server app:

```
curdoc().add_root(p0)
curdoc().add_root(p1)
curdoc().add_root(p2)
curdoc().add_root(p3)
curdoc().add_root(p4)
```

They can all be placed in responsive Bootstrap layouts:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    {{ embed(doc.roots[0]) }}
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    {{ embed(doc.roots[1]) }}
    <br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    {{ embed(doc.roots[2]) }}
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    {{ embed(doc.roots[3]) }}
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    {{ embed(doc.roots[4]) }}
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds good ! Bokeh is really awsome, and you are magic : exhume an old post to give relevant and free answer... Respect ! Unfortunately I didn't had a lot of time to continue my project, but I followed bokeh development and was waiting for this feature. Good occasion to code again. I will test your suggestion soon. Thanks for the poke and the example !

Comment: long time later: I've tested suggested solution and it works as expected ! Merci beaucoup !